# Proving $ \sum_{l=1}^{2n} (-1)^{l+1}\frac{1}{l}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}$ by induction

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

How to prove this by induction?

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{2n} (-1)^{l+1}\frac{1}{l}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} \text{ for } n \in \mathbb N$$

I got the beginning $A(1)$ is true, but I'm getting stuck somewhere in the middle of the proof for $A(n+1)$.

This is how far I got:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use MathJax for to write your problem.

Comment: the second sum does not depend on $k$

Comment: Remember to add delimiters `$$` around your math expressions for them to show up as such. Also something must be missing, since the left sum is an integer but the right is never an integer.

Comment: The formula is clearly false.

Comment: Now the equation is true. For the inductive step, try to find what is common between the case $n$ and the case $n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there; you just need to see that

\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{n+k+1}=\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac1{n+k} &= \frac1{n+n+2}+\frac 1{n+n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k} - \frac1{n+1}
\\&=\frac1{2n+2}+\frac 1{2n+1}- \frac2{2n+2} + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}
\\&=\frac 1{2n+1}- \frac1{2n+2}+ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}\end{align}

and you can finish the induction.